# Linear algebra - Showing a set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Show $\{1, \cos(t), \cos^2(t), \cos^3(t)\}$ is a linearly independent set.

I know that we can take derivatives of the "dependence relation", then plug in values of t to make some terms vanish.

However, I am unsure of how to get the equations and show the results from using the calculator to solve for the unknown coefficients.

Comment: My teacher never talked about that in class. All he suggested was taking the derivatives of the dependence relation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

**First method:**

1) Prove that : $$V=\text{Span}\{1,\cos t, \cos^2 t,\cos^3t \}=\text{Span}\{1,\cos t,\cos(2t),\cos(3t)\}$$
2)Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that $$\forall t \in \Bbb R \quad f(t) =a_0+a_1\cos t+a_2\cos(2t)+a_3\cos(3t)=0$$

By computing:  $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \cos (kt) dt $$ for all $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ show that $$\forall k \in \{0,1,2,3\} \quad a_k=0$$

That means that $\dim (V)=4$  and  the set $\{1,\cos t, \cos^2 t,\cos^3t \}$ is linearly independant.

**Second method:**
Let $b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3$ such that $$\forall t\in \Bbb R \quad \sum_{k=0}^3 b_k(\cos t)^k=0$$
Then:
$$\forall x \in [-1,1] \quad P(x)=0$$
Wher $P$  is the polynom : $P(X)=b_0+b_1X+b_2X^2+b_3X^3$

That means $P$ has infinity of zeros, then $P=0$  and  $b_0=b_1=b_2=b_3=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the linearization formulas.
Then, eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

I will prove that $\{1,\cos(x),\cos^2(x),...,\cos^n(x)\}$ is linearly independent. This is equivalent to showing that...

$$c_0 + c_1\cos(x) + c_2\cos^2(x) + ... + c_n\cos^n(x) = 0 \implies c_0 = c_1 =\ ...\ = c_n = 0$$

First, note that at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ each term in the expansion drops except $c_0.$ This implies that $c_0 = 0.$ Now we must just show that

$$c_1\cos(x) + c_2\cos^2(x) + ... + c_n\cos^n(x) = 0 \implies c_1 = c_2 =  \ ... \ = c_n = 0$$

This holds if and only if

$$c_1 + c_2\cos(x) + ... + c_n\cos^{n-1}(x) = 0 \implies c_1 = c_2 =  \ ... \ = c_n = 0.$$

It is clear that we should proceed with an inductive argument because if $\{1,\cos(x),\cos^2(x),...,\cos^{n-1}(x)\}$ is linearly independent then $\{1,\cos(x),\cos^2(x),...,\cos^n(x)\}$ must be linearly independent as well.

Clearly the case where $n = 1$ is true:$$c_0 = c_1\cos(x) \implies c_0 = c_1 = 0$$

so it must be true for all $n$ $(\in \mathbb{N}).$